# Would an object travel forever if thrown in space?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity, free-body-diagram, vacuum

for example, let's say you have an object like a stone or pencil and it is thrown at a certain velocity in space (also pretend that there are no planets, stars, black holes, or any other things that can obstruct or force the object to orbit, so just empty space, nothing else) would objects speed increase over time or decrease or stay moving at the same speed forever?

Comment: If you extend the question a bit and include the thrower of the object as part of the system the answer is a little more interesting.

Comment: i added an answer since you are new to this site, but generally, I think this kind of question would get downvoted or removed since it's widely discussed online. usually the expectation is that you do some research and represent that in your question, so just keep this in mind for future questions you might ask. hope my answer helped. :)

Comment: This might be a deeper question than it seems, because a spacetime containing only a single non-accelerating mass has a reference frame where that mass is at rest. There has to be something else, perhaps far away, so that you can answer the question “traveling relative to what?”

Comment: hi @rob , i think this is probably well beyond what the user is asking. i assume this person is a high school student just learning physics. i saw you put another answer to a similar question about a stone that seems rather inaccessible (in my opinion) to someone at this perceived level. i see what you mean with your points, but maybe we can ask the user to first clarify what their level is?

Answer (score 2):

If there is no force to act on an object, there won't be anything to change the motion of that object. We can look at Newton's first and second laws to understand this more. According to Wikipedia, Newton's first law is formulated as "a body remains at rest, or in motion at a constant speed in a straight line, unless acted upon by a force". Newton's second law, which reads $F=ma$, telling us that we need a force to give rise to an acceleration (and, thus, a change in velocity). So, the answer to your question is yes, if we have an initial state (described by law 1, this doesn't change), then we'd need something (a force as described by law 2) to change this motion.